# Python: Create New Fields in Dataframe Efficiently Based on Values in Existing Fields

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, field

Currently, I have the following data frame table:

[image]

This is the table I want to create (desired columns highlighted in yellow):

[image]

Below are the logic I want to implement in the code:

- Create a new column for each of the existing columns in the table and add _Weight to the column name.
- If column value is not null, assign a certain number of points to each row that is not null (in my example 50 to Advisor_Weight column and 100 to the other ones).

I know how to do this the slow / inefficient way where I manually create each new column using np.where type of statement.

I am wondering ... is there an efficient looping way to do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have this data in Pandas DataFrame it's really simple:

here is my sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],['Significant',np.NaN, np.NaN],[np.NaN, "Yes", np.NaN], ["Significant", np.NaN, "Top Advisor"]], columns=['Advisor', 'Retirement', 'Recognition'])
```

[image]

```
columns_50_points = [df.columns[0]]
columns_100_points = df.columns[1:]

for col in columns_50_points:
    df[col+"_Weight"] = ~df[col].isnull() * 50

for col in columns_100_points:
    df[col+"_Weight"] = ~df[col].isnull() * 100
```

First I specify which columns are worth how much by assigning them to one of lists.

~df[col].isnull() this checks if value is not null, if True just multiply by your weight.

After that DataFrame looks like this:
[image]

but you can reorder the columns, to make it look better.

```
df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

[image]

I hope it helps

EDIT:

In case if your fields are not NaNs and just empty strings, you can replace them with NaNs. To do so just apply this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(), axis=1).replace("", np.NaN)
```

So first each string is trimmed, then replaced with NaNs. If after that you want to go back to empty strings it's as easy as

```
df.fillna("")
```

if your nans are also strings, just add this to strings in replace method like this: replace(["","nan"], np.NaN)

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation above; unfortunately, when I apply your code to my dataframe ... the _Weight column does not recognize the NaN ; so for example, every row in Advisor_Weight field equals 50; my dataframe shows the blanks as nan --> does that impact anything?